# How can we use the symmetry of this complex matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Find the Jordan normal form of $A\in \mathbb C^{4,4}$ if A is symmetric, $A^2=A$ and $\operatorname{rank} A=3$.

So $A^2=A$ implies that the only eigenvalues are $0$ and $1$. From $\operatorname{rank} A=3$ we get the multiplicities. But how do we use the symmetry? I was hoping that it would imply normality (so we could use the usual unitary diagonalization) but it doesn't since we can't count on $A\bar{A}=\bar{A}A$.

I've just read about [Autonne-Takagi factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix#Complex_symmetric_matrices) but the text I got the exercise from doesn't cover it, so I expect it to be some simpler trick.

Comment: Are you sure that it should be symmetric rather than Hermitian?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: yes, that's exacty what confuses me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, the other information is enough to deduce the Jordan normal form.  We have $A^2 - A = 0$, which implies that the minimal polynomial of $A$ divides $x^2- x = x(x-1)$.

It follows that $A$ is diagonalizable with eigenvalues $1$ and $0$.  We then note that the rank of $A$ must be the multiplicity of the eigenvalue $1$ (verify that this is the case for a diagonal matrix).  Thus, $A$ has the normal form
$$
\pmatrix{
1\\
&1\\
&&1\\
&&&0
}
$$

Comment: It didn't occur to me that the piece was in fact redundant. Many thanks!

Comment: No problem. I suppose that symmetry would be important if we were to look for the similarity that puts the matrix in its Jordan form.